# Mark the radio button checked after clicking the anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the anchor tag, the radio button inside it must be marked as checked. The data is coming through a loop so there is a large amount of data.  Here is my code:

```
<a class="toggleanchor sectionsdiv accordion-toggle <?php if($i!=1){ ?> collapsed <?php } ?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne<?=$i;?>">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="padding:0;">
            <div class="checkbox checkreward">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" <?php if($i==1){ ?> checked <?php } ?> class="form-control radio-height" id="radioid<?=$z;?>" value="<?=$reward['amt'];?>"/> $<?=$reward['amt'];?>
                    <input type="hidden" id="giftval-<?=$z;?>" value="<?= ucwords($reward['gift']);?>"/> 
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="hight-light<?=$z;?>" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 textreward">
            <h2><?=  ucwords($reward['entry']);?></h2>
            <h4 class="text-uppercase text-white">    
                <b><?=$reward['sup'];?></b>
            </h4>
        </div><!--.col1 text-center-->
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
</a>
```

This anchor is repeated in the loop, so the data will change every time. how can i make it work? I tried different code but couldn't get it to work. Like

```
$(".toggleanchor").click(function(event) {    
    $(radio).attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105447/how-can-i-toggle-radiobutton

Comment: It's invalid HTML to put a radio button (or any other interactive content) inside an `<a>` tag. It won't work properly in Internet Explorer.

Comment: It is disgusting regardless of validity.

Comment: @mplungjan no argument there.

Comment: @jumojer that Q is different form this one

Comment: @Pointy i don't care it work or not in IE which i need is make it work in other browser, do you have any solution. Thanks

Comment: The solution is to not use that sort of markup. It really makes no sense; what's the point of the `<a>`?

Comment: If you don't like the `<a>` wrapping a radio you can just use a `<div>` there instead and make it clickable via jQuery. I think you can also just about make it work if you wrap it with a `<label>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

please use this...

```
$(".toggleanchor").click(function(event) {    
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
});
```