# How can I uncheck radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code looks like this :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/m7by6zcw/6/

I want the radio button to be unchecked. So if the radio button is checked, it can be unchecked again.

How can I do it?

Comment: `radio` buttons can't manually be "unchecked", so maybe look into using a `checkbox` that unchecks all others with the same name when clicked, or handle the `click` function of a `radio` to uncheck it if it's checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105717/3710195

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings('input[type="radio"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

And adding an attribute 'data-waschecked' to your radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="spain" data-waschecked="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is more simple

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct, you set the input's checked property to false.

```
inputElement.checked = false;
```

but I think I understand what you are trying to do (uncheck on clicking a checked option), and it is a bit more tricky than that in my experience. The problem has to do with the the checked property always resolving to true when you look at it in response to an event, because the change happens before your event handler fires. To resolve this I have always set a custom property on the element to track what was checked prior to the current eventloop.

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
radios[i].addEventListener('click', uncheckIfChecked);
}

function uncheckIfChecked(event){
if(event.currentTarget.alreadyChecked) event.currentTarget.checked = false;
updateChecked();
}

function updateChecked(){
 for(var x = 0; x < radios.length; x++){
   if(radios[x].checked == true){
     radios[x].alreadyChecked = true;
    }else{
     radios[x].alreadyChecked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>England</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england"> Chelsea
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england"> Mu
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="england"> Arsenal
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><strong>Spain</strong></li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain"> Madrid
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain"> Barcelona
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="spain"> Atletico
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Not sure if that is exactly what you were looking for, but hopefully that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Execute a function that sets the `checked` property of the radio button to false.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `form` and add a reset button, then it returns to it's original state.

```
<form>
...
<input type="reset">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m7by6zcw/7/